# cp: cannot stat ‘path/file’: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, vagrant, provisioning

I try to copy a file from host to vagrant box via vagrant provisioning:

```
command = "cp #{File.join(Dir.pwd,'install.sh')} /home/vagrant/"  # /home/user/vagrant/install.sh  /home/vagrant
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => command
```

but then I get:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/user/vagrant/install.sh’: No such file or directory
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!


Stderr from the command:
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/user/vagrant/install.sh’: No such file or directory
```

---

**The file is located in the same directory as the Vagrantfile and  I can access the file on the mentioned path**

Comment: When you say you can access it on the mentioned path, do you mean you can ssh in, and then access it within the VM at `/home/user/vagrant/install.sh`?

Comment: I meant I can access it from the host not vagrant box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell provisioner runs the given command on the vagrant box, not on the host system.

Since the host directory with the Vagrantfile (and, in this case, your install.sh) is mounted as `/vagrant` in the vm, changing the command to `cp /vagrant/install.sh /home/vagrant` should to do trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another work around:

I created a `nfs` directory called `shared` and copied the `install.sh` file in the nfs directory and shared it to my vagrant box by adding the below snippet in the Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "shared", "/home/vagrant/shared"
```